# Swift label text seems to be its own node

Tags: swift, option-type

I am building a SpriteKit game in which a player drags a checker around the scene. I use nodesAtPoint to determine what other nodes this checker encounters, and I look for various SKNode.name values to determine what behavior to trigger.  However, "nil" kept showing up in my array of nodes and troubleshooting helped me determine that the node showing up as "nil" was in fact the text of an SKLabelNode.  The label node has the name "label" and it is in the array as a separate element from the text of the label.  So I figured I had two options:

1. name the text "node" (which I cannot see how to do)
2. make the node.name string optional, and ignore nil values.

I tried the latter:

```
    for node in nodesArray {
        if let nodeName: String = node.name {
            if nodeName.hasSuffix("dropZone") == true {
                println("drop zone encountered")
            }
        }

    }
```

However, I am not getting this to work well. I am getting the error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
           if let nodeName: String? = node.name {
                if let tempNodeName = nodeName {
                    if tempNodeName.hasSuffix("dropZone") == true {
                        // code goes here
                    }

                }
            }
```

Essentially I failed to add the '?' after String in the first line.